# Iterating skipper function

Tags: python, string, int, iterable

Currently using Python 3.3. I'm currently having a bit of a problem finding out how to write a function that takes one `iterable` and one `int` as parameters and produces values from the `iterable`, starting at the first and skipping the number of values specified by the `int`.

My code is as follows:

```
def skipping(iterable,n=0):
     _iters = iter(iterable)
     try:
         while True:
             current = next(_iters)
             count = n
             while count != 0:
                 count -= 1
                 current = next(_iters)
             count = n
             yield current
     except StopIteration:
         pass
```

When I call `skipping('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 1)`. I get with `.join()`:

```
bdfhjlnprtvxz <---- Wrong output
```

I want to get:

```
acegikmoqsuwy <---- Right output
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) already provides this:

```
def skipping(iterable, n=0):
    return itertools.islice(iterable, 0, None, n+1)
```

The documentation also provides near-equivalent Python code for `islice`:

```
def islice(iterable, *args):
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2) --> A B
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, 4) --> C D
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 0, None, 2) --> A C E G
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxint, s.step or 1))
    nexti = next(it)
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)
```

---

The bug in your code is that you go skip, yield, skip, yield instead of yield, skip, yield, skip. You need to yield an element first, before you start skipping elements:

```
def skipping(iterable,n=0):
     iterable = iter(iterable)
     try:
         while True:
             yield next(iterable)
             for _ in xrange(n):
                 next(iterable)
     except StopIteration:
         pass
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use itertools built-in module, it's an exercise, so I would like to know how I would work around it. Haha.

Comment: @user2559679: See the provided equivalent Python code for `islice`.